# How to fix "missing some pkg-config macros" error?

Tags: bash, installation, zeromq

I'm trying to install zeromq on OS X 10.11.2. To do this, the following shell commands were suggested:

```
cd libzmq
./autogen.sh && configure && make -j 4
```

But when I enter the second line, I get the following errors:

```
configure.ac:59: error: missing some pkg-config macros (pkg-config package)
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:68: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIBTOOL_WIN32_DLL
configure.ac:69: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
configure.ac:253: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR
configure.ac:427: error: missing some pkg-config macros (pkg-config package)
configure:6315: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_STATIC
configure:6319: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_ENABLE_STATIC
autoreconf: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
autogen.sh: error: autoreconf exited with status 0
```

How can I fix this and successfully install zeromq?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Install pkg-config

```
apt-get install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not install anything manually. This adds unmanaged libraries and headers to your file system and you will meet a lot of problems in future. Use homebrew instead

```
brew install zeromq
```

If you really want to compile and install it manually - you are missing pkg-config, which itself must be installed - either via homebrew, or by compiling it manually.

```
cd /tmp
curl -OL https://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/releases/pkg-config-0.29.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf pkg-config-0.29.1.tar.gz
cd pkg-config-0.29.1
./configure --with-internal-glib
make
sudo make install
```